# How do i display a span when i hover over an area (image map) in css?

Tags: html, css

I have an image of the solar system, I need to display a span above the image, for example, "The sun" when I hover over the sun how do I do that

```html
 <div class="map">
            <div id="p-name">
                <p> 
                    <span class="nsun">The sun</span>
                    <span class="nmerc">Mercury</span>
                    <span class="nvenu">Venus</span>
                    <span class="nearth">Earth</span>
                    <span class="nmars">Mars</span>
                    <span class="njupi">Jupiter</span>
                    <span class="nsat">Saturn</span>
                    <span class="nura">Uranus</span>
                    <span class="nnep">Neptune</span>
                    <span class="npluto">Pluto</span>
                </p>
            </div>
            <img class="map" src="map.png" alt="Solar map" usemap="#solarmap">
            <map name="solarmap">
                <area class="sun" shape="circle" coords="145,285,140" alt="The sun">
                <area class="merc" shape="circle" coords="332,300,22" alt="Mercury">
                <area class="venu" shape="circle" coords="400,300,36" alt="Venus">
                <area class="earth" shape="circle" coords="478,300,36" alt="Earth">
                <area class="mars" shape="circle" coords="549,300,26" alt="Mars">
                <area class="jupi" shape="circle" coords="669,300,82" alt="Jupiter">
                <area class="sat" shape="circle" coords="835,309,77" alt="Saturn">
                <area class="ura" shape="circle" coords="1004,309,60" alt="Uranus">
                <area class="nep" shape="circle" coords="1134,309,60" alt="Neptune">
                <area class="pluto" shape="circle" coords="1226,309,12" alt="Pluto">
            </map>
        </div>
```

Comment: what have you tired?  Please include the code that you have tried and where you have challenges with it perhaps

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery `.mouseenter()` and `.mouseleave()` events to trigger what you need. See https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/. And I would suggest to use data attributes on maps to make it more dynamic, otherwise you'll need to match the case for each planet (What will happen if we discover a new one ?? ;-) ).

Or alternatively, if you don't want to use jQuery, you can follow the example given at w3schools: https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_imagemap

Comment: Please include an example rather than just links to somewhere else perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CSS`

`:hover`

Example

```
#p-name{

display:none;

}
.sun:hover + .nsun{

disply:block!important;

}
```

Just make sure you place your map before the spans

so your HTML will look like this

```
 <div class="map">
            <img class="map" src="map.png" alt="Solar map" usemap="#solarmap">
            <map name="solarmap">
                <area class="sun" shape="circle" coords="145,285,140" alt="The sun">
                <area class="merc" shape="circle" coords="332,300,22" alt="Mercury">
                <area class="venu" shape="circle" coords="400,300,36" alt="Venus">
                <area class="earth" shape="circle" coords="478,300,36" alt="Earth">
                <area class="mars" shape="circle" coords="549,300,26" alt="Mars">
                <area class="jupi" shape="circle" coords="669,300,82" alt="Jupiter">
                <area class="sat" shape="circle" coords="835,309,77" alt="Saturn">
                <area class="ura" shape="circle" coords="1004,309,60" alt="Uranus">
                <area class="nep" shape="circle" coords="1134,309,60" alt="Neptune">
                <area class="pluto" shape="circle" coords="1226,309,12" alt="Pluto">
            </map>
            <div id="p-name">
                <p> 
                    <span class="nsun">The sun</span>
                    <span class="nmerc">Mercury</span>
                    <span class="nvenu">Venus</span>
                    <span class="nearth">Earth</span>
                    <span class="nmars">Mars</span>
                    <span class="njupi">Jupiter</span>
                    <span class="nsat">Saturn</span>
                    <span class="nura">Uranus</span>
                    <span class="nnep">Neptune</span>
                    <span class="npluto">Pluto</span>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
```